# How to display content based on two dropdownlists in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json

I want to display content based on two dropdownlists. I know how to change based on options with single dropdownlist. Kindly help me regarding this.

This is to display based on single drop downlist. I have another dropdownlist with Branchwise. I am strucked to filter the data based on CAREER and BRANCHES. Kindly helpme

```
<select ng-model="myVar">
<option value="">CAREER OPTIONS
 <option value="1">HIGHER EDUCATION
  <option value="2">JOBS
  <option value="3">ENTERPRENUERSHIP
</select>

<div ng-switch="myVar">
  <div ng-switch-when="1">
 <h1>H E details</h1>
  </div>
<div ng-switch-when="2">
 <h1>Jobs details</h1>
 </div>
<div ng-switch-when="2">
<h1>Enterprenuership details</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: help without code on mere texts?

Comment: Kindly give me one example so that i can use.

Comment: Kindly support me @manish

Comment: have you tried it!?  provide some code

Comment: Phase share what you have tried. Then only we can help.

Comment: @Rajesh540 check my plnk out

Comment: Yeah Thankyou @manish. Its working as per my needs. Thanks alot!

Comment: Thanku! But a small sugession. Not the message. I want to change the Menu names. In one selection three menus will come. Any suggesstion for that? @manish

Answer (score 0):

here's working [plnk](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZXGeSoeFb7qC1FbEwRCv?p=preview), this does exactly the same you need, based on selection from `2 dropdown/select` the `message` changes

Comment: Thanku! But a small sugession. Not the message. I want to change the Menu names. In one selection three menus will come. Any suggesstion for that? @manish

Comment: In the plunker when i replace numbers (options) in the dropdownlist with words,it does not working. Any string modifications? @manish

Answer (score 0):

Add `ng-if` in each section

```
<select ng-model="myVar1" ng-change="myVar3 = (myVar1+myVar2)">
    <option value="">CAREER OPTIONS
    <option value="1">HIGHER EDUCATION
    <option value="2">JOBS
    <option value="3">ENTERPRENUERSHIP
</select>

<select ng-model="myVar2" ng-change="myVar3 = (myVar1+myVar2)">
    <option value="">Branch OPTIONS
    <option value="1">Branch 1
    <option value="2">Branch 2
    <option value="3">Branch 3
</select>

<div ng-if="myVar3 ">
    <div ng-if="myVar3 == '11'">
        <h1>H E details</h1>
    </div>
    <div ng-if="myVar3 == '12'">
        <h1>Jobs details</h1>
    </div>
    <div ng-if="myVar3 == '13'">
       <h1>Enterprenuership details</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ng if two condiions ? one from Parent Dropdown and the other from child dropdown?

Comment: How to use ng if to filter data based on two dropdownlists? @JihinRaju

Comment: @Rajesh540 Pls look at now, I have changed the answer

Comment: Thankyou! But my porblem is this should come in menu bar actually. Based on the selection the next three menu bars should change. Here only one message change correctly. But how to change all the three menus? Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The code you edited is displaying all he divs  when loading. Not displaying the exact as the first one. Any modifications? @Jihin Raju

Comment: what u mean by "displaying all he divs when loading" - @Rajesh540

Comment: All divs are displaying. Not filtering based on selection as in the first one before editing.

Comment: is there any jfiddleor plunker? its not working for me. It displaying all the divs.

Comment: Thanks a bundle! You helped me alot bro. But i am dying with my exact requirement. . The thing is here i have to display this in menu bar. At a time i have to change 3 menus.  By this i got some idea. Any further suggestions pls bro. @Jihin Raju

Comment: Bro its working but i did not understand the js file. Where are the scope values? @Jihin Raju

Comment: if your face any problem in this, you can post the comment under this question I will help you and don't forget to approve my answer  @Rajesh540

Comment: sure bro!  But where are the scope values in app.js? How this is working?

Comment: values directly added in HTML page - @Rajesh540 ng-change="myVar3 = (myVar1+myVar2)"

Comment: I did not get bro how it will consider as myVar==11,12,13? @Jihin Raju

Comment: I add the 2 models(myVar1, myVar2) with + operator then assign to myVar3, the result is combination of myVar1 and myVar2

Comment: i got that how how it will be equal to 11,12,13  myvar1+ mYvar2 values how equals to myvar3? Previoulsy we given scope values but here how?

Comment: previously both values are undefined when the dropdown value is changed it will work

Comment: In that case we can give any number? I i want to add for JOBS and Enterprenuership also,then what values i have to give?

Comment: pls add it in plunker and give the link

Comment: Same lke for what we done for higher education in. I wnat to do for all the other options also. But one thing clarify bro why only 11 12 13 vlaues ? i did not get still? @Jihin Raju

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview  Bro when i even copy and paste your exact code also it not working. Confused alot. @Jihin Raju

Comment: you give any values in a dropdown and that will decide what is the out put

Comment: Ok now got full clarity bro. Previously i was adding the values 1+1 =2. But now i got full clarity. Thanks alot.

Comment: I am very new to this so some problem. But a big thnks from my side forgiving your valuable time. Thanks alot once again bro.

Comment: i an unable to make it bro. But shall i send the pics of my requirement?

Comment: don't forget to approve my answer